# <!DOCTYPE HTML> causes hamburger nav bar javascript to not function

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I apologize for my lack of coding knowledge as I am fairly new to web designing. I've searched for a solution for days, trying different methods, and realized I need help.

Basically my code is programmed to illustrate a hamburger icon when the browser is shrunk, this works perfectly fine. What I am having issues with is that when I click on my hamburger icon, the dropdown menu will not display.

It used to work when I didn't add the  line in the beginning, but my site was really slow and laggy. After adding the line, my javascript does not work at all and I'm lost.

Here is my code for html, css and js:

```js
$('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
 if ($('.menu').hasClass('open')) {
   $('.menu').removeClass('open');
 } else {
   $('.menu').addClass('open');
}
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 30px;
    display: block;
  }

  .line {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    width: 35px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
  
  .line:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  
  /* Our styles here */
#nav li {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
text-align: center;
border-top: 1px solid white;         
border-bottom: none;
background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}

.menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-top:-14;
}

.open {
    height: 255;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<div id="nav">
      <div href="#" class="hamburger">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
   <ul class="clearfix menu">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

please msg if I need to provide any more info!!

Comment: so little code, why not put it in the question, like you should, not in an external link that helps nobody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving the `ul.open` a height of `255` but the browser needs to know the unit (px/em/rem etc.). Setting this to `255px` will fix your issue.

The reason you are experiencing this after setting a doctype is because by doing so you are setting your document to be rendered in standards mode instead of quirks mode. In standards mode you must specify units for dimensions, in quirks mode the browser assumes px.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this last time by editing it to 255px but it didn't resolve it, I forgot that I also have to set the menu height to 0px as well instead of just 0